# ios JSON mapping object

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

I'm working on iOS app in Swift.

I use RealmSwift, ObjectMapper and ObjectMapper_Realm to get data from a JSON file and to save it in Realm.
Until now it worked fine, but I got an array of String without extracting key at the same level of an other object and I don't know how to do...

Here is my object:

```
 "books": 
    [
            {
              "id": 56436886, 
              "type": "Book",
              "title": "Title of the book",
              "authors": [
                         "Name FirstName",
              ]
            }
    ]
```

and here is my class for mapping:

```
class Book: Object, Mappable {

// MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
private struct SerializationKeys {

    static let id = "id"
    static let type = "type"
    static let title = "title"
    static let authors = "authors"

}

// MARK: Properties
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var type: String?
@objc dynamic var title: String?
var authors = List<Author>()

// MARK: ObjectMapper Initializers
/// Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper.
///
/// - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper.
convenience required init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

// MARK: - Model meta informations
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return []
}

/// Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper.
///
/// - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper.
public func mapping(map: Map) {

    id <- map[SerializationKeys.id]
    type <- map[SerializationKeys.type]
    title <- map[SerializationKeys.title]
    authors <- (map[SerializationKeys.authors], ListTransform<Author>())

}
```

}

And here is my Author class:

```
class Author: Object, Mappable {

@objc dynamic var authorName: String?

// MARK: - Model meta informations
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "authorName"
}

convenience required init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    self.authorName <- map
}
```

}

I don't know how to map in the Author class, so when I get my JSON object, all my book is saved exept for authors...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to map without using intermediate `Author` entity? Strings array mapping should work fine.
Check out https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm.

Also, `map` has `currentKey` and `currentValue` properties which may contain what you need to use with `Author` entity usage.

Comment: I tried this solutions but couldn't make any work, I had an array of String but empty, and I think it is not the best to don't have an Author Entity. Maybe I didn't try the right way. Finally I worked with:

if let tmpAuthors = map.JSON[SerializationKeys.authors] as? [String] {
            for author in tmpAuthors {
                let authorObject = Author()
                authorObject.authorName = author
                authors.append(authorObject)
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
It works fine with:

```
  if let tmpAuthors = map.JSON[SerializationKeys.authors] as? [String] {
        for author in tmpAuthors {
            let authorObject = Author()
            authorObject.authorName = author
            authors.append(authorObject)
        }
    }
```